# How to update JAVA version on Linux servers?

Tags: java, linux, oracle

I have a set of Linux servers on which I launch a vulnerability scanning.
The vulnerability rapport shows a huge number of Java Patching types.

For example for one server, the rapport shows me :

```
Vulnerable software installed: Oracle JRE 1.8.0.201 (/app/oracle/product/19.3.0.0/client_1/jdk/jre/lib/rt.jar)
Vulnerable software installed: Oracle JRE 1.8.0.201 (/app/stage/Components/oracle.jdk/1.8.0.201.0/1/DataFiles/Expanded/filegroup2/jre/lib/rt.jar)
Vulnerable software installed: Oracle JRE 1.8.0.201 (/var/tmp/OraInstall2022-01-12_02-29-33PM/jdk/jre/lib/rt.jar)
Vulnerable software installed: Oracle JRE 1.8.0.201 (/tmp/OraInstall2022-01-12_02-29-33PM/jdk/jre/lib/rt.jar)
Vulnerable software installed: Oracle JRE 1.8.0.201 (/tmp/OraInstall2022-01-12_02-00-46PM/jdk/jre/lib/rt.jar)
```

Could you please provide me with detailed steps on how to update java on this server as it's running on a production environment and I have to carefully update the version?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to reinstall necessary packages? They should give an option to update

Answer (score 0):

Most of the results you listed appear to be false positives:

```
Vulnerable software installed: Oracle JRE 1.8.0.201 (/app/stage/Components/oracle.jdk/1.8.0.201.0/1/DataFiles/Expanded/filegroup2/jre/lib/rt.jar)
Vulnerable software installed: Oracle JRE 1.8.0.201 (/var/tmp/OraInstall2022-01-12_02-29-33PM/jdk/jre/lib/rt.jar)
Vulnerable software installed: Oracle JRE 1.8.0.201 (/tmp/OraInstall2022-01-12_02-29-33PM/jdk/jre/lib/rt.jar)
Vulnerable software installed: Oracle JRE 1.8.0.201 (/tmp/OraInstall2022-01-12_02-00-46PM/jdk/jre/lib/rt.jar)
```

These all appear to be related to the installation process, and not actual running code. You can most likely delete anything in /tmp and /var/tmp, and should consider archiving (zip and compress) /app/stage content if you want to avoid these report results.

The last JRE is in your actual ORACLE_HOME directory; this is the only one that really needs to be patched:

```
Vulnerable software installed: Oracle JRE 1.8.0.201 (/app/oracle/product/19.3.0.0/client_1/jdk/jre/lib/rt.jar)
```

Embedded Java in ORACLE_HOME can be patched. I wrote a blog post about it a couple of years ago. See here: https://pmdba.wordpress.com/2018/08/20/patching-the-java-jdk-in-oracle_home/.

Essentially you will need to:

1. Identify which JRE version you have (Java 8 in your case)
2. Get the latest Java update from Oracle Support (a current support contract and customer service identifier is required) and
3. Replace the old one with the new one while the database is stopped (rename old JRE directory, unzip new one into the original location, remove the old one).

See the referenced MOS Doc IDs in the blog for details.

> You can confirm which version of the Java JDK your Oracle Home is using with the following command:

```
 $ORACLE_HOME/jdk/bin/java -version
```

> Once your Oracle Home directory is
> confirmed as using JDK version 7 or 8, you can use MOS Doc ID
> 2584628.1 to identify the latest JDK updates for each major release available for download from My Oracle Support. Note that this document
> also lists a one-time Perl patch for install on all 11g, 12c, and 18c
> releases.

Comment: I can't see steps to do to update versions from your blog post ?

Comment: Read the referenced MOS Doc IDs. The steps are specific to your version.

Comment: The important details for this answer are "in another castle". You should include **ALL** relevant details in this answer (including MOS IDs) so that if/when link-rot occurs then the answer is still relevant.

Comment: already edited to do that...